# Android device with two push notification ids

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

All is working well with my push notifications, but after to update new Google Play Services  I am seeing on the Logcat that my device has a new push identification, my first id was (google play services 16) "APA91b3..." and the new one (google play services 17) is "APA91bHr..." and the amazing is that both works fine.

My questions is:
Why I have two push ids with the same device?
On my DB I have the first(version 16) id saved. Do I need to update it with the new id?
I´m very confused with that. I don´t know if I am doing something wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app registers to GCM multiple times, it usually receives the same registration ID from Google. However, sometimes it can get a different registration ID (to me it usually happens when I uninstall the app and install it again, but perhaps there are other occasions in which it happens).

Both registration IDs would work, but sending GCM messages from your server with the old registration ID would result in Google returning a response that contains the new registration ID (also called canonical registration ID). Google ask that in that case you delete the old registration ID and use only the new one. They say that the old registration IDs may stop working at some point, though I haven't encountered such behavior yet.